# C++ endl not printing new line when called from a method

Tags: c++, endl

New to C++
My understanding is endl will add a new line. So with the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printf(string message);

int main()
{

cout << "Hello" << endl;
cout << "World" << endl;

printf("Hello");
printf("World");

return 0;

}

void printf(string message) {
cout << message << endl;
}
```

I expect the output to be:

Hello

World

Hello

World

But, strangely, the output is:

Hello

World

HelloWorld

Looks like, when called from the user-defined method, endl is not adding new line..??
What is wrong with my understanding here. Please advise.

Comment: Are you sure it is *your* printf() that is called? I suspect it is the CRT version...

Comment: Maybe one should be a tad bit more careful with namespaces then?!

Comment: Due to overload resolution the built in `printf` function is selected over your custom defined `printf` function. To solve this, replace the `printf` calls with : `printf(string("Hello"));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **problem** is that due to **overload resolution** the built in `printf` function is selected over your custom defined `printf` function. This is because the **string literal** `"Hello"` and `"World"` **decays** to `const char*` due to **type decay** and the built in `printf` function is a better match than your custom defined `printf`.

To **solve** this, replace the `printf` calls with :

```
printf(std::string("Hello"));
printf(std::string("World"));
```

In the above statements, we're explicitly using `std::string`'s constructor to create `std::string` objects from the **string literal** `"Hello"` and `"World"` and then passing those `std::string` objects by value to your `printf` function.

Another alternative is to put your custom `printf` inside a custom namespace. Or you can name your function other than `printf` itself.

Answer (score 2):

It's using the inbuilt printf method.
Try to explicitly use std::string so that it'll call custom printf method.

```
printf(std::string("Hello"));
printf(std::string("World"));
```

Or you can put your method in a different namespace:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace test
{
    extern void printf(const std::string& message);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "World" << std::endl;

    test::printf("Hello");
    test::printf("World");

    return 0;

}

void test::printf(const std::string& message) {
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pick function name other than `printf();` like `Print()`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try renaming the "printf" function to "print" it works fine-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void print(string message);

int main()
{

cout << "Hello" << endl;
cout << "World" << endl;

print("Hello");
print("World");
cout <<endl;
return 0;

}

void print(std::string message) {
cout << message << endl;
}
```